# How to clip outer area of circle in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have drawn semi circle in swift using `UIBezierPath` the parent is `UIImageView` now i am looking to clip the outer area of circle. I have tried `clipsToBounds` but it didn't works.

[image]

```
   let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: -60, y: imgView.frame.size.height/2),
                           radius: imgView.frame.size.width*1.3,
                        startAngle: CGFloat(90).toRadians(),
                        endAngle: CGFloat(270).toRadians(),
                        clockwise: false)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
    imgView.clipsToBounds = true
    imgView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

extension CGFloat {
    func toRadians() -> CGFloat {
        return self * .pi / 180
    }
}
```

EDIT:1 **i have tried `imgView.layer.mask = shapeLayer` but it wipes out `strokeColor`**

Comment: @matt Thanks for input . i have tried `imgView.layer.mask = shapeLayer` but it wipes out `strokeColor`

Comment: You have to mask the area outside the stroke width

Comment: @matt thanks ! by `reversing()` i have done it.

Answer (score 1):

try :- `imgView.layer.maskstoBounds = true`

Answer (score 1):

A shape layer either draws on top of another layer or, if you use it as a mask, clips another layer. It can't do both at the same time.

You need **two** shape layers. Leave the one you have now, stroked in blue, as a sublayer of your image view layer.

Create a second shape layer, install another circle path into it, set it's **fill** color to any opaque color, and use that second shape layer as a mask on your image view. You might need to add a stroke color and borderWidth to your mask layer so it is big enough not to mask your blue circle. (I forget if strokes are drawn inside, outside, or centered on the edge of their shape boundaries. I think they are centered, so unless you also stroke your mask layer at the same thickness, it will clip the outer half of your blue circle shape layer, but I'd have to try it to be sure.)

Comment: Thanks @DuncanC. i have tried something similar.  used `reversing` on `UIBezierPath`